Given $G, H \subseteq S_n$, such that $G \neq H$, and $K$ a maximal subgroup of both, prove there exists no element $p \in G \cap H$ but $p \notin K$
$G \neq H$ are subgroups of the symmetric group $S_n$, each containing the subgroup $K$ which is maximal in both. Assume there exists an element $p \in G \cap H$, but $p \notin K$.
Edit: $G \not\subset H$ and $H \not\subset G$. This appears to be the assumption I was missing as pointed out in the comments.

Since the intersection of groups is also a group, $G \cap H = L$ must
be a proper subgroup of both $G$ and $H$ such that $K$ is a subgroup
of $L$ and $p \in L$. However, since $K$ must be a maximal subgroup of
both $G$ and $H$, if $K$ is a subgroup of $L$, then $L$ must also be a
subgroup of $K$. Therefore, it must be that $K = L$. Since $K = L$,
due to the assumption, it also must be the case that $p \notin L$.
However, since we assumed $p \in L$, this results in a contradiction,
and no such $p$ can exist.

I’ve convinced myself that this is true, that if two different groups share a maximal subgroup, then there is no other element shared outside of this subgroup. It’s just when writing the proof, something feels like it is missing or I’m convoluting things. In the problem that led me to this question, $G$ and $H$ are both primitive groups and $K$ is a maximal stabilizer. However, it feels like this should generalize pretty readily to all finite groups, so I didn’t include the extra assumptions in the proof.

Looks good to me. $K\le G\cap H\le G$, so by maximality $K=G\cap H$ or $G=G\cap H$.

Yeah, what if $G$ contains $H$?

Ahh ok, I was missing the case when $G \subset H$ or $H \subset G$ which I want to exclude. I’ll update the question with this extra assumption which looks to make everything work as I’d like. Thanks for pointing that out!

@Malady If $G$ contained $H$ then $K$ could not be maximal in them both

@Nalim You don't need the extra assumption, because it follows from the fatc that $K$ is a maximal subgroup of both $G$ and $H$. You don't even need to assume that the groups are finite, as long as $G$ and $H$ are both subgroups of some larger common group.

@DerekHolt That’s awesome to know that this even extends to the infinite case! Your comments would definitely be an answer to the question, so if you add one, I’ll gladly accept it!
